# Sass: Can't load kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version

Tags: sass, installation

I have just install sass using:
`choco install sass` on windows.

when i try to run `sass --version` the error `Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version` on the console.

Would anyone know what the problem might be?

I installed dart beforehand using the installer. would that have cause a problem and i am not using flutter.